# Android Virtual Device on Macbook Pro with Retina Display

Tags: android, android-virtual-device, retina-display

I'm programming on Android Studio with a MBP with retina display. But when I launch the avd(I try with nexus 5 and 7 avds) it looks grainy(very poor quality). 
The OS is 10.10.2 and the Android Studio version is 1.0.2.

Comment: Same for me. Any idea?

Comment: Right now I'm using genymotion's emulators, but the best solution maybe is to use an external full hd monitor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I'll try with Genymotion. :)